# How to find and remove strings with case insensitive match?

Tags: java

In Java, I have a file contains lines like:

```
abc
cbd
CFG
...
```

I want to remove CFG from the file if any of the lines matchs a string, which could be 'cfg', 'Cfg', or other case insensitive variations.

If I read the file into a Set, how can I achieve this? It seems more feasible to do this by reading the file into a List.

Comment: You could do something like uppercase the string and insert into the set.

Comment: `String.equalsIgnoreCase(String str)`

Comment: Then when you print out, you lost all the original cases, which is not what I need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following is a "lambda version" of the required code.  Thanks to [@Sam](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4405881/sam) for the important point about re-raising any suppressed PrintWriter IOException.

```
Path in_file = Paths.get("infile");
Path out_file = Paths.get("outfile");
try (PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(out_file.toFile())) {
    Files.lines(in_file)
         .filter(line -> !line.equalsIgnoreCase("cfg"))
         .forEach(pw::println);
    if (pw.checkError()) {
        throw new IOException("Exception(s) occurred in PrintWriter");
    }
}
```

If you need to modify the file in place, then writing to it while reading from it is somewhat more difficult.  You could read it all into memory first.

```
Path path = new Path("filename");
List<String> lines = Files.lines(path)
                          .filter(line -> !line.equalsIgnoreCase("cfg"))
                          .collect(Collectors.toList());

try(PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(path.toFile())) {
    lines.forEach(pw::println);
    if (pw.checkError()) {
        throw new IOException("Exception(s) occurred in PrintWriter");
    }
}
```

And finally, just in case, a non-lambda solution for compatibility with Java 7:

```
Path in_file = Paths.get("infile");
Path out_file = Paths.get("outfile");
try (BufferReader reader = Files.newBufferedReader(in_file);
         PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(out_file.toFile())) {

    String line;
    while((line = reader.readline()) != null) {
        if (!line.equalsIgnoreCase("cfg")) {
            pw.println(line);
        }
    }
    if (pw.checkError()) {
        throw new IOException("Exception(s) occurred in PrintWriter");
    }
}
```

Comment: Nice!  I didn't know that!

Comment: @Sam - Ya, handy that `PrintWriter`.  Now if they only had a `.collect(toFile(path))` collector, this could be a "one-liner"!

Comment: Though I've just read about it some more and it literally swallows Exceptions.  I think I would be happier if it threw a RuntimeException for production use so I at least end up something in a log if it's gone a bit wrong.

Comment: @Sam - You can call `if (pw.checkError()) { throw new IOException("Stream had errors"); }` at the end of the `try { }` block.  Perhaps not quite as informative, but really you just care that there was a problem, and where it occurred for the most part.

Comment: Yeh I realised that would have the be the compromise :)

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?

```
try (BufferedReader bf = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(new File("PATH TO FILE")));
     BufferedWriter bw = new bw(new FileWriter(new File("PATH TO NEW FILE")))) {
  bf.lines()
      .filter(line -> !line.equalsIgnoreCase("cfg"))
      .forEach(line -> {
        try {
          bw.write(line);
        } catch (IOException e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
        }
  });
}
```

The only ugly thing is the need for two trys because of not being allowed to throw exceptions from lambdas.

Comment: A `PrintWriter` suppresses the exceptions for you.  See my answer.

Comment: `BufferedReader#lines()` removes the newline characters from the stream of lines.  You need to add it back in, with `bw.write(line).newLine();`.

Comment: Whoops!  `bw.write(line); bw.newLine();` You can't chain `BufferedWriter` methods.

Answer (score 0):

You can search for the string in the list and remove that using a position.

```
public List<String> removeItemInListIgnoreCase(List<String> items, String itemToRemove){
        if(CollectionUtils.isEmpty(items)) 
        return new ArrayList<String>();
        for(int i=0; i<items.size();i++) {
            if(items.get(i).equalsIgnoreCase(itemToRemove)) {
                items.remove(i);
            }
        }
        return items;
    }
```